# Problem with aligning an enumerate-environment with multicol-package right after \paragraph{}

Tags: sectioning, lists, enumerate, multicol, sections-paragraphs

I am trying to use the `multicol` package to save vertical space while using the enumerate environment. To use a specific example, if I had 3 items in a list, I'd rather they not stack vertically, but be on the same row.

More specifically, I am trying to separate a set of answers to a physics problem from the problem statement itself neatly, and to this end I decided to use the `\paragraph{}` command.

This all works just fine, except when I try to place the `multicols` environment with the enumerated list inside of it right after a `\paragraph{}`. This is what I get:

[image: Ugly alignment]

Here ''Vastaukset:'' is inside the `\paragraph`. It's obvious this does not look very good. Here is a MWE code sample that produces the *unwanted* result:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,finnish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Vastaukset:}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
\item 2,70 fm ja 3,5 fm,
\item 4,26 fm ja 5,6 fm,
\item 6,34 fm ja 8,3 fm.
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

If I were to place text between the `\paragraph{}` and `multicols` the list items would align themselves just fine:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,finnish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Vastaukset:}
aaa
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
\item 2,70 fm ja 3,5 fm,
\item 4,26 fm ja 5,6 fm,
\item 6,34 fm ja 8,3 fm.
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: The desired alignment]

I was unable to find the solution to this specific problem through the search functionality on this site, and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I think, you should rather look for the `tasks` package

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tasks` package which is especially meant for horizontal lists and has a sophisticated interface for configuration of behaviour and typesetting:

```
\begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk[a])](3)
    \task \SIrange{2,70}{3,5}{\femto\metre}
    \task \SIrange{4,26}{5,6}{\femto\metre}
    \task \SIrange{6,34}{8,3}{\femto\metre}
 \end{tasks}
```

will setup a 3-column - wide horizontal list and lowercase 'numbering' (tsk[a]).

The `\SIrange` command is used to improve the formatting of numbers and units.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,finnish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{range-phrase={ ja }, copy-decimal-marker}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Vastaukset:}
aaa
\begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk[a])](3)
\task \SIrange{2,70}{3,5}{\femto\metre}
\task \SIrange{4,26}{5,6}{\femto\metre}
\task \SIrange{6,34}{8,3}{\femto\metre}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]